# Copying a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

Could some one tell me why the memory address of the localComplete block and the self.block are the same?  self.complete's property is set to copy, and just to be sure i also call copy on localComplete when assigning it to self.complete.

```
- (void) test {

    CompletionBlock localComplete = ^{

    };

    NSLog(@"localComplete - %p", localComplete);

    self.block = [localComplete copy];

    NSLog(@"self.complete - %p", self.block);

    self.block();
}
```

Here is the output:

```
2013-10-05 08:39:18.549 TestApp[90703:a0b] localComplete - 0x60b8
2013-10-05 08:39:18.550 TestApp[90703:a0b] self.complete - 0x60b8
```

---

As another example I create strings:

```
// creating string
self.carType = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Good%@", @"year"];
NSLog(@"self.carType - %p", self.carType);

// same memory address???
NSString *carInitString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: self.carType];
NSLog(@"carInitString - %p", carInitString);

// same memory address???
NSString *carCopy = [self.carType copy];
NSLog(@"carCopy - %p", carCopy);

// different memory address
NSString *carInitWithFormat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@", self.carType];
NSLog(@"carInitWithFormat - %p", carInitWithFormat);
```

And the output:

```
2013-10-05 09:45:01.667 TestApp[91103:a0b] self.carType - 0xa084910
2013-10-05 09:45:01.668 TestApp[91103:a0b] carInitString - 0xa084910
2013-10-05 09:45:01.668 TestApp[91103:a0b] carCopy - 0xa084910
2013-10-05 09:45:01.668 TestApp[91103:a0b] carInitWithFormat - 0xa336b70
```

Why isn't carInitString and carCopy different memory addresses?  Optimizations are turned off in the projects build settings.

Comment: in simple words, the block does have code which is at some fixed memory location and it is assigned to a sort of function pointer which is pointing to the block so the address of pointer is same i.e of block's code.

Comment: Try copying the block outside of test() and see.

Comment: Fair enough, but the same thing happens when I create a local NSString and then create another instance of it by calling copy.  It's the same memory address for both.  If I create that 2nd NSString with [[NSString alloc] initWithString: firstString] I still get the same memory address.  It's only when I create the 2nd string  by using [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@", firstString] do I get what I expect which is 2 different memory addresses.  It sounds like a compiler optimization but if it's not could you explain.  Thanks

Comment: NSString although supports the NSCopying protocol DOES NOT implement copyWithZone: there fore you would have to subclass NSString make a method that does the reallocation for you and return that new string

Comment: and call that method copyWithZone

Comment: tehcnically if NSString super class had the copyWithZone method it would copy, but the super class is NSObject which doesn't even conform to the NSCopying protocol

Comment: @A'saDickens Nonsense. The `NSString` class conforms to the `NSCopying` protocol, and therefore *must* implement `copyWithZone:`. Try this little experiment yourself: send an `instancesRespondToSelector:` message to the `NSString` class and see what it returns.

Comment: i did, when you click to view the header file of NSString, it doesn't contain that method, unless this method is private

Comment: Most objects are able to respond to copyWithZone: but not all of them implement it at the level needed to copy the object correctly

Comment: @A'saDickens That's also wrong. Most objects do not implement `-copy`. Many container objects do. If they do they will declare that they implement the `NSCopying` protocol. That's basically equivalent to declaring your class implements the methods of `NSCopying`. Those classes that do implement `NSCopying` better make sure they properly implement `-copy` Where are you getting these ideas from?

Answer (score 3):

Concerning your original question, blocks are normally allocated on the stack. Copying a block (either with the `Block_Copy` function or the `-copy` method) will move the block on the stack (further calls will just increase the block's retain count)

> Block_copy [...], given a block pointer, either copies the underlying block object to the heap, setting its reference count to 1 and returning the new block pointer, or (if the block object is already on the heap) increases its reference count by 1

([source](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html))

So in your example, you may expect different addresses, since the first block is local, whereas the second one is on the heap, **BUT** since that specific block doesn't make any reference to the surrounding scope, the compiler will mark it as a global block. Global blocks are not allocated on the stack, and are instead at a fixed location in memory.

Copying a global block won't move the block anywhere. It will just increase its retain count, since the object is already on the heap. That's why you don't get two different addresses.

Try to make a block with a reference to the surrounding context and you will have two different addresses (stack and heap).

---

Now, let's address your question about `NSString`.

Copying an immutable object can result in a `retain` as an optimization (I mean, a framework design optimization, the compiler has nothing to do with it), depending on how the class implements the `NSCopying` protocol.

This is true for many Foundation classes like `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSSet`...

This is perfectly compliant with the `NSCopying` protocol specification, as you can read in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> Your options for implementing this protocol are as follows:
>
> ...
>
> - Implement NSCopying by retaining the original instead of creating a new copy when the class and its contents are immutable.

As noted by Greg Parker in the comments, `-[NSString initWithString:]` performs the same kind of optimization. If you pass an immutable string as argument, it just retains and return the same string.

---

This is a useful behavior in a few situations, here's an example: you declare a property

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *anArray;
```

and you expose it in the interface.

Declaring it as `copy` is a good practice in order to ensure that the object you are working on doesn't get changed by the client later on. If you just retain it and the client passes in a `NSMutableArray` you cannot prevent her to manipulate the object.

So copying is good, but it looks like it comes with a price: you are going to copy the object even when you don't need to (i.e. it's immutable).

Thanks to the behavior discussed above, however, you don't pay such price. Sending `copy` to an `NSArray` will just retain it, whereas sending it to a `NSMutableArray` will actually copy it, so in this case is a big win.

Comment: And -[NSString initWithString:] performs the same optimization: if you create a constant string from another constant string, it simply retains and returns the same string.

Comment: Yep good point, I forgot to mention that specific case. Thanks.

Comment: This should be accepted as the valid response! Really good clarifications about memory management.

Answer (score 1):

it could be because the copy isn't necessary. you don't capture any variables or anything like that. so perhaps the block is constant. try having it refer to a local or __block variable.